# Can I upgrade windows 8.1 to 10 and not affect ubuntu?

Tags: windows, 15.04

I am very curious as to how it will affect bios settings. And how it will affect grub2. I have dual booted 15.04 with windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how your system is configured.  Normally, if Windows is installed after Linux, it over-writes the MBR or bootsector of the drive installing its own BCD.  Windows BCD does support multiboot to Ubuntu, but it is not as elegant as GRUB is.  You can reinstall GRUB after if that happens by following the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I have a GPT drive and I just used the D: drive for ubuntu 14.10 then I upgraded to 15.04

Comment: @nerd7473 I too have multiple drives in my system.  I have had the Windows installation over-write my GRUB, but was able to install it back to `/dev/sda` which contains my Windows.  But then I found that was becoming a pain to have to keep doing that, so I flipped drives, and now my Ubuntu boots first, and Windows is on my secondary.  So now I just disconnect my Ubuntu drive for installing Windows to avoid problems.  Then after it is installed I boot back to my Ubuntu, and then I update grub after for the new windows change.

Comment: I only have one physical drive the C: and D: drives were present when I got the laptop

Comment: @nerd7473 Ah, then yes, there is a big chance it will over-write it.  If you follow that link all the way through it works great to reinstall GRUB.

Comment: @nerd7473 You might need to install `gdisk` so that you can list your drive so you can mount the partition correctly with GPT.  After gdisk is installed, you list it by `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`  Then your partition is the number in front, so if it has 2, then your partition would be `/dev/sda2`

Comment: Instead of fixing grub2 can I just switch bios settings and put the ubuntu bootloader before the windows bootloader? Would that work? I am using an asus x550la 1TB HDD, 8GB RAM, and an Intel core i7

Comment: @nerd7473 I don't think the BIOS supports selecting what bootloader you're going to boot from.  At least I have never heard of that.  I believe that when the BIOS Post is complete, it hands off the loading to the MBR of the drive that is selected for booting, and since your system has one hard drive in it, it will default to booting to that drive.  Here is some info about how BIOS boot partition works:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition

Comment: I have done this when I had to rollback windows 8.1 to 8. Just g I t into the bios and it had the boot tab, I went to it and moved the ubuntu before the windows boot manager...

Comment: @nerd7473 Ah, that is what I get for having older equipment.  ;)  If that is the case, and the BIOS (UEFI)  supports it, then yes, you should be fine!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting

Comment: Ok well then my work here is done so just install 8.1 then 10 then switch back to ubuntu should work but I will clone my drive to be on the safe side

Comment: @nerd7473 Sounds like a plan!  Good luck with the update to Windows 10, and yes, it is always a good idea to clone (backup) before upgrading any OS.  Also looks like I need to invest in newer hardware for my system!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally it shouldn't do anything. I would suggest a backup tho in case the installation process fails. I did this myself and no problems where to be seen.

Comment: Can clonezilla backup the drive without cloning it?